# LEFT JOIN include records which don't exist

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**Properties**
`property_id, col1, col2 ...`

**Images**
`image_id, property_id, serial, ...`

Serial in Images table is just 1,2,3,4... (upto the number of images a property has). Serial=1 means default image.

I want to fetch all properties with only their default image. So I do:

```
SELECT * FROM properties p 
LEFT JOIN images i ON p.property_id = i.property_id 
WHERE i.serial=1
```

It works very well. But I noticed that many properties don't have images at all. So they don't appear in the results. I want to select all those properties as well which don't have any image at all. How can I do this?

EDIT:
Can I do something like
`WHERE (i.serial = 1 OR count(i.serial)=0)`

Comment: No. You can't use COUNT() in the WHERE clause. But you can use COUNT() in the HAVING clause.

Comment: To use COUNT() in HAVING, the query must be a GROUP query. Right?

Comment: HAVING will usually have a GROUP BY. But it would be better, if you posted some sample data and the desired result - with explanation why this is the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

If using an outer join and having a condition on the joined table, you've got to include this condition in the join condition.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    properties p 
LEFT JOIN 
    images i 
ON 
    p.property_id = i.property_id 
AND 
    i.serial=1
```

If you use this condition in the WHERE clause you change your OUTER join implicitly to an INNER one.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there:

```
SELECT * FROM properties p 
LEFT JOIN images i ON p.property_id = i.property_id 
WHERE i.serial IN (1,NULL)
```

For every property where there is no image, all the values in the images table will be `NULL` in the result. So you have to allow for that. You can actually see it, if you leave out the `WHERE` part for testing.

Comment: This where is equivalent to `WHERE i.serial = 1 OR i.serial=NULL` right?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can also use `OR i.serial IS NULL`. `IN()` is a shorter syntax for an `OR` on the same column.

Comment: This is a `INNER JOIN` and no more `LEFT JOIN`. See @VMai answer.